# What is the necessity of using interfaces in Java callbacks?

Tags: java, interface, callback

what is the difference between this two implementaions? Is it necessary to use an interface?

the first snipet uses interface the second does not

```
// interface implementation of callback
interface OnSearchListener {
    void onFound(String result);
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Search search = new Search();
        search.searchForSomething(new OnSearchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFound(String result) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        });

    }
}

class Search {
    public void searchForSomething(OnSearchListener searchListener) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                System.out.println("searching....");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        searchListener.onFound("found some result");

    }
}
```

****************

this is a callback without using an interface

```
class Search {
    public void searchForSomething() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                System.out.println("searching....");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Main main = new Main();
        main.onFound("found some result");
    }
}

class Main {

    public void onFound(String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Search search = new Search();
        search.searchForSomething();

    }
}
```

what is the importance of using the interface in callbacks? and what are the pros and cons of not using it?

Comment: [code reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse), how would you do it if you need to use `searchForSomething` in a different codebase since it's bound to `main`?

Comment: Note that in the 2nd case you create a new instance of `Main`, so that is not a callback. In a callback you'd be calling back an existing instance of `Main`, in your example to deliver back search results.

Answer (score 2):

The term "callback" doesn't fit to the second implementation, as that's just a fixed method call.

"Callback" means that I supply code (in your case the `OnSearchListener`'s `onFound()` method) to some function (`searchForSomething()`) asking it to call my code when some criteria are met. So, without any variability in the code supplied it isn't a callback.

Of course, if you have full control over both sides (`Main` and `Search`) and will only ever want one code snipped to get called, you don't need a callback, and that's your second implementation.

But if you want a real callback, you need an abstraction that defines the method signature, but not the implementation that is to be called, and that typically is an interface in Java, but (bad style!) could also be an abstract class or even a normal base class.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are always good to use if you have multiple implementations.. What if in the scenario you mentioned you different version of onFound?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples and oranges.

- The first case is a callback.
- The second case is not a callback.

In the second case you create a new instance of `Main` with `Main main = new Main();` so that is not a callback. In a callback you'd be calling back an existing instance of `Main`, in your example to deliver back search results.

You could make `Main` a singleton so there would only ever be one instance of `Main`, but that way of communicating between classes is out of scope of your question and has certain drawbacks, depending on your use case.